# Background image did not display properly when print (Save as PDF) but can be used

Tags: html, css, codeigniter, pdf, printing

I would like to print a report, but when i try to save as PDF, the background image won't work even I using own images. The background image only works when viewing a document but won't work at print.

```
<style>
        #title td {
            font-weight: bold;
            border: none;
        }

        .vcenter {
            vertical-align: middle !important;
        }

        .heading-yellow {
            background-color: antiquewhite;
            /* -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important; */
        }

        .table-bordered>tbody>tr>td,
        .table-bordered>tbody>tr>th,
        .table-bordered>tfoot>tr>td,
        .table-bordered>tfoot>tr>th,
        .table-bordered>thead>tr>td,
        .table-bordered>thead>tr>th {
            border: 2px solid #000;
        }

        .table-bordered {
            border: 2px solid #000;
        }


        body {
            /* background-image: url('<?php echo base_url("/backend/background/Watermark Raport.png") ?>'); */
            background-image: url('<?php echo base_url("/backend/report/Watermark_Raport.png") ?>');
            font-size: 9pt;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
        }

        .description-text {
            font-size: 8pt;
        }

        .section {
            break-inside: avoid;
        }

        @media print {
            .pagebreak {
                clear: both;
                page-break-after: always;
            }

            .section {
                break-inside: avoid;
            }

            .heading-yellow {
                background-color: antiquewhite;
                -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
            }

            body {
                /* background-image: url('<?php echo base_url("/backend/background/Watermark Raport.png") ?>'); */
                background-image: url('<?php echo base_url("/backend/report/Watermark_Raport.png") ?>');
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: cover;
                -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
            }

            .col-md-7 {
                width: 58.333333%;
            }
        }
    </style>
```

Even @media print won't work. The print preview, even I using background graphics, did not work properly.

[background-image works, but print preview won't display properly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4Dca.png)

Anyone know how to solve this? So when I print preview, the image is appeared properly.

Comment: Check your browser print settings. Browsers seem to often set no background printing as default. You will probably have to scroll down to find something like more options on print and select print background.

Comment: I test in my firefox and it worked well.